# How would I output just the first letter of each word from a string? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am completing an NEA for my GCSE assessment, and need help with a certain piece of code.
The task requires me to create a music quiz in which the Artist of the song and the first letter of each word of the song title is displayed. I don't know how I would even start to do this. Currently I have the songs in an array from an external file and can output a random one based of a random number generator but need help manipulating the string.
Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: That's not a question for SO. You need to work out the logic first - how would you do it with pen and paper; that's how you would do it in code too - and then try to write code to implement that logic. If your implementation doesn't work as expected, then you can show us what you've done and explain exactly how its behaviour differs from your expectation.

Comment: when you have finished writing down your algorithm like @jmcilhinney wrote you will find plenty of tutorials regarding string manipulation on the net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each character individually in VB.NET by accessing it as if it were an array. So if you have for example:

```vb
Dim s As String = "abcdef"
```

Then if you use brackets like it is an array you can return a single character.
So to get the first element would be:

```
Dim first_letter As String = s(0) ' This would return just "a" as it is the first item and arrays are 0 indexed
```

And to find each element you can do s(1), s(2) etc or whatever your string is called as a string is an array of characters so they can be accessed and manipulated like one.